# In Delphi, is it a correct approach to Free the Sender within an Event?

Tags: delphi, pascal

So, say we have a class like this:

```pascal
  TFieldsReadyEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; Code, AuthorizatedID: string) of object;
  TCatcherServer = class(TServer)
  private
    FOnFieldsReady: TFieldsReadyEvent;
    FCode: string;
    FAuthoID: string;
    FAuthorizationType: TAuthorizationType;
    function GetAuthorizationType: string;
    function GetCode: string;
    function GetEntityID: string;
  public
    property OnFieldsReady: TFieldsReadyEvent read FOnFieldsReady write FOnFieldsReady;
    property Code: string read GetCode;
    property EntityID: string read GetEntityID;
    property AuthorizationType: string read GetAuthorizationType;
    procedure Callback(Session: TIdContext; Req: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; Res: TIdHTTPResponseInfo); override;
  end;
```

Where the `Callback` procedure looks like this:

```pascal
procedure TCatcherServer.Callback(Session: TIdContext;
  Req: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; Res: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  inherited Callback(Session, Req, Res);
  if (Req.Params.Values['code'] <> '') and ((Req.Params.Values['shop_id'] <> '') or (Req.Params.Values['main_account_id'] <> '')) then
  begin
    Res.ResponseNo := 200;
    Res.ResponseText := '{"message":"continue on the application"}';
    FCode := Req.Params.Values['code'];
    if (Req.Params.Values['shop_id'] <> '') then
    begin
      FAuthorizationType := atShopAuthorization;
      FAuthoID := Req.Params.Values['shop_id'];
    end else
    begin
      FAuthorizationType := atMainAccountAuthorization;
      FAuthoID := Req.Params.Values['main_account_id'];
    end;

    FOnFieldsReady(Self, FCode, FAuthoID);
  end else
  begin
    Res.ResponseNo := 400;
    Res.ResponseText := '{"message":"Something went wrong."}';
  end;
end;
```

Is it a correct approach to have in my form an event handler that is able to Free the TCatcherServer instance? Example as follows:

```pascal
{Form1 public declarations}
procedure FieldsReadyHandler(Sender: TObject; Code, AuthorizatedID: string);
```

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  VarServer := TCatcherServer.Create;
  VarServer.Listen(7070);
  VarServer.OnFieldsReady := FieldsReadyHandler;
end;

procedure TForm1.FieldsReadyHandler(Sender: TObject; Code,
  AuthorizatedID: string);
begin
  ServerLog.Lines.Add(Code);
  ServerLog.Lines.Add(AuthorizatedID);
  ServerLog.Lines.Add((Sender as TCatcherServer).AuthorizationType);

  Sender.Free;
end;
```

**TL;DR** Is it the correct approach to use events to free the sender in cases like this (where after the event is triggered I got the data I needed and don't need the Sender anymore). If not, what's the correct way of doing so?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, creation and destruction should occur on the same level. Whoever fired the event and created the object before that should destroy it after.

Comment: @Kromster, if the event is ran asynchronously, how can I destroy the object in a simple Try...Finally without risking to destroy before the event happens. Ideally, I'd need to wait for an event THEN free the object.

Comment: I would probably and a callback into the event arguments, that would return the control to the caller, where caller can synchronize it the way it sees fit.

Comment: But wouldn't letting the caller control it imply into freeing TCatcherServer inside TCatcherServer?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your implication. One more note though, who will free your `TCatcherServer` if you dont enter the branch with the `FOnFieldsReady` event?

Comment: I mean: Isn't TCatcherServer the caller of the FOnFieldsReady's procedure? About the note, I'm not sure if I understand but the sole purpose of TCatcherServer is to listen for a request from the OAuth system, I'm considering blocking the Listen method if the event is not assigned or even assign it on the constructor. (Tho it is not even visible in the user accessible class)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is usually NOT safe to free the `Sender` from inside its own event. You don't know what else may still need to access the `Sender` after the event handler exits.

Case in point - if the `Sender` in question is the object that owns the `TIdHTTPServer` which is triggering your `Callback()` method, then you would be trying to free the `Sender`, and thus free the `TIdHTTPServer`, while `TIdHTTPServer` is still waiting for the `Callback()` to exit.  Since `TIdHTTPServer` is a multi-threaded component that fires its `OnCommand...` events in worker threads, destroying the `TIdHTTPServer` in its own event would cause a deadlock.

If you must free the `Sender`, you should do so *asynchronously* so you give the caller/RTL extra time to finish using the `Sender`. For instance, by using `TThread.Queue(nil, Sender.Free);` (just be aware that `TThread.Queue()` runs its predicate in the main thread, so make sure your `Sender`'s destruction is thread-safe in this example).

Comment: Isn't ``Release`` used instead of ``Free`` for such a case!?

Comment: `Release()` only applies to `TForm`, and the `Sender` in this case is not `TForm` it is `TCatcherServer`. Also, `TForm.Release()` is only safe to call in the context of the main thread, not in a worker thread, due to its use of the thread-unsafe `TForm.Handle` property getter.

Comment: What's the actual difference between ``Release``/``Free``? Also, (maybe a dumb question) you said that freeing inside ``OnFieldsReady`` I'll free ```TIdHTTPServer`` while it's still waiting for ``Callback()`` to exit. As procedures don't return, how does it work internally, thus what makes it needed to wait for a procedure to exit.

Comment: @ArthurAraujo `Free` destroys immediately. `Release` posts a `CM_RELEASE` message to the `TForm` window and then destroys it in the message handler. The `TIdHTTPServer` destructor terminates its worker threads and waits on them, so if destroying `TCatcherServer` will also destroy the `TIdHTTPServer` and you destroy the `TCatcherServer` in the `OnFieldsReady` event then the `TIdHTTPServer` will end up waiting on the same thread that is destroying it.